# How do I skip .svn folders with File::Find?

Tags: perl

I am writing a Perl script that is iterating over file names in a directory and its sub-directories, using the following method:

```
find(\&getFile, $mainDir);

sub getFile {
    my $file_dir = $File::Find::name;
    return unless -f $file_dir;    # return if its a folder
}
```

The file structure looks like this:

```
main/classes/pages/filename.php
```

However because of version control each folder and subfolder has a hidden `.svn` directory that has duplicates of every file inside with a `.svn-base` suffix:

```
main/.svn/classes/pages/filename.php.svn-base
```

I was wondering if there is a return statement like the one I had previously using:

```
return if ($file_dir eq "something here");
```

to skip all the `.svn` folders to not find filenames with the `.svn-base` suffix. I have been fiddling around with regex and searching for hours without much luck. I have only been using perl for couple days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
return if ($file_dir !~ /\.svn/);
```

(`!~` is equivalent to `!($file_dir =~ /\.svn/)`. The `=~` operator compares a variable with a pattern.

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a spin.  I always confused about the usage of those regular expression. They are very useful but sometimes hard to get my head wrap around how they work. Thanks a bunch for fast reply